# Writing dynamic query results into file

Tags: groovy

I am trying to write a generic program in Groovy that will get the SQL from config file along with other parameters and put them into file.

here is the program:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("config.properties").toURL())
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(config.db.url, config.db.login, config.db.password, config.db.driver);

def fileToWrite = new File(config.copy.location)
def writer = fileToWrite.newWriter()
writer.write(config.file.headers)

sql.eachRow(config.sql){ res->
    writer.write(config.file.rows)
}
```

in the config the sql is something like this:

sql="select * from mydb"

and

file.rows="${res.column1}|${res.column2}|${res.column3}\n"

when I run it I get

> [:]|[:]|[:]
>
> [:]|[:]|[:]
>
> [:]|[:]|[:]

in the file. If I substitute

```
 writer.write(config.file.rows)
```

to

```
writer.write("${res.column1}|${res.column2}|${res.column3}\n")
```

it outputs the actual results. What do I need to do different to get the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You accomplish this by using lazy evaluation of the Gstring combined with altering the delegate.
First make the Gstring lazy by making the values be the results of calling Closures:

```
file.rows="${->res.column1}|${->res.column2}|${-> res.column3}"
```

Then prior to evaluating alter the delegate of the closures:

```
config.file.rows.values.each {
    if (Closure.class.isAssignableFrom(it.getClass())) {
       it.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
       it.delegate = this
    }
}
```

The delegate must have the variable res in scope. Here is a full working example:

```
class Test {
Map res

void run() {
    String configText = '''file.rows="${->res.column1}|${->res.column2}|${-> res.column3}"
    sql="select * from mydb"'''
    def slurper = new ConfigSlurper()
    def config = slurper.parse(configText)

    config.file.rows.values.each {
        if (Closure.class.isAssignableFrom(it.getClass())) {
           it.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
           it.delegate = this
        }
    }

    def results = [
            [column1: 1, column2: 2, column3: 3],
            [column1: 4, column2: 5, column3: 6],
        ]

    results.each {
        res = it
        println config.file.rows.toString()
    }
}
}
new Test().run()
```

Comment: I learned something new today. Always a good day when that happens.

Comment: I tried it and still get the same result - [:]|[:]|[:].

Comment: when you check the class of `config.files.rows` what is it? `config.files.rows.getClass()` should be a GString. You have to call `config.file.rows.toString()` when `res` is in scope too.

Comment: It is gtoovy.util.ConfigObject

Comment: @BalRog it has to be specified as `config.file.rows.getClass()` in order to not have the map return the value of the `'class'` key

Comment: @Dylan Bijnagte, both `config.file.rows.class` and `config.file.rows.getClass()` return the same thing: `class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`. Sorry for the aborted comment above (now deleted) but I hit return accidentally and didn't notice it until my 5 minute window was past.

Comment: after setting `it.delegate = this` the closure parameter `res` is *still* not visible to the new delegate. That is why it continues to fail. However, *Global variables* are visible from the new delegate, so renaming the closure parameter to something else and then assigning it to a global named `res`... works.

Comment: yay, that worked for me, the only change I needed to make is to change from Map res to def res since res couldn't automatically be converted to Map from whatever class is used for sql results (it showed com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7).

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that the `ConfigSlurper` is more than capable of doing the `GString` variable substitution for you as intended. The bad news is that it does this substitution when it calls the `parse()` method, way up above, long before you have a `res` variable to substitute into the parser. The other bad news is that if the variables being substituted are not defined in the config file itself, then you have to supply them to the slurper in advance, via the `binding` property.

So, to get the effect you want you have to parse the properties through each pass of `eachRow`. Does that mean you have to create a new `ConfigSlurper` re-read the file once for every row? No. You *will* have to create a new `ConfigObject` for each pass, but you can reuse the `ConfigSlurper` and the file text, as follows:

```
def slurper = new ConfigSlurper();
def configText = new File("scripts/config.properties").text
def config = slurper.parse(configText)
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(config.db.url, config.db.login, config.db.password, config.db.driver);

def fileToWrite = new File(config.copy.location)
def writer = fileToWrite.newWriter()
writer.write(config.file.headers)

sql.eachRow(config.sql){ result ->
    slurper.binding = [res:result]
    def reconfig = slurper.parse(configText)
    print(reconfig.file.rows)
}
```

Please notice that I changed the name of the Closure parameter from `res` to `result`. I did this to emphasize that the slurper was drawing the name `res` from the binding map key, not from the closure parameter name.

If you want to reduce wasted "reparsing" time and effort, you could separate the `file.rows` property into its own separate file. i would still read in that file text once and reuse the text in the "per row" parsing.

Comment: I tried this and it runs out of memory with Caught: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Adding     reconfig = null in the end of closure didn't help. Why does it use the memory, shouldn't it be freed for each row?

Comment: There is no guarantee when (or if) garbage collection will run. Try `int i = 1` before `sql.eachRow` and `if (!(i%100) System.gc())` as the first statement in the closure. Having said that, have you tried @Dylan Bijnagte 's solution? It looks pretty efficient, especially compared to mine.

Comment: I did try it, but I get the same result - [:]|[:]|[:]